# How do I pass a var to onPress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a value/string from a JSON file which is assigned to a, that can then be passed to handleAnswerQuestion.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99gUk.jpg)

```
var a = { myData.results[count].category[count] }

<TrueButton onPress={() => this.handleAnswerQuestion(a)}>

const TrueButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 50;
  backgroundColor: rgba(106,227,104, 0.8);
`
```

Comment: the way you are doing, what is the problem?

Comment: i get an error of - cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function.

Comment: ah i fixed the above, get a new error message. look at my updated Q

Comment: The error message or css appear to be complete unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass value on your custom class **TrueButton**. And then you can pass like this:

```
<TrueButton onPress={(valueFromCustomClass) => this.handleAnswerQuestion(valueFromCustomClass)}>
```

**valueFromCustomClass** is a value which you passed from your custom class.

Comment: truebutton isnt a custom class. i've added the code for truebutton in the q